# Python tkinter with pyautogui

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

I want to create mouse mover, I write 2 separate codes. One for mouse moving and other for tkinter app, and now i don't know how to combine it. Can some help me? Thanks for your time!

**Mouse Mover:**

```
import pyautogui as pag
import random
import time

text = "AFK Bot is running. Each 5 seconds mouse will be moved."

print(text)

while True:
    x = random.randint(200,1000)
    y = random.randint(300,1200)
    pag.moveTo(x,y,0.5)
    time.sleep(5)
```

**Tkinter app:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('AFK Bot!')
root.geometry("500x300")

global is_on
is_on = True

my_lable = Label(root,
                 text="The Switch is On!",
                 fg="green",
                 font=("Helvetica", 32))
my_lable.pack(pady=20)

def switch():
    global is_on
    if is_on:
        on_button.config(image=off)
        my_lable.config(text="The Switch is Off",
                        fg="grey")
        is_on = False
    else:
        on_button.config(image=on)
        my_lable.config(text="The Switch is On",
                        fg="green")
        is_on = True


on = PhotoImage(file="images/on.png")
off = PhotoImage(file="images/off.png")

on_button = Button(root, image=on, bd=0, command=switch)
on_button.pack(pady=50)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt your mouse move code to work with tkinter:

```py
import pyautogui as pag
import random
import time

text = "AFK Bot is running. Each 5 seconds mouse will be moved."

print(text)

def mover(root):
    x = random.randint(200,1000)
    y = random.randint(300,1200)
    pag.moveTo(x,y,0.5)
    root.after(5000, lambda:mover(root))
```

And call this once before mainloop:

```py
mover(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Update:**

To switch the `mover()` function on and off the same as the `is_on` variable, you could add a flag to the function:

```py
def mover(root):
    if mover.flag:
        x = random.randint(200,1000)
        y = random.randint(300,1200)
        pag.moveTo(x,y,0.5)
    root.after(5000, lambda:mover(root))
```

and condition the flag:

```py
is_on = True
mover.flag = is_on
```

and update the flag:

```py
def switch():
    global is_on
    if is_on:
        on_button.config(image=off)
        my_lable.config(text="The Switch is Off",
                        fg="grey")
        is_on = False
    else:
        on_button.config(image=on)
        my_lable.config(text="The Switch is On",
                        fg="green")
        is_on = True
    mover.flag = is_on
```

Comment: thanks, but when i click OFF its still moving mouse.

Comment: I didn't realise that was one of the requirements.

Comment: How I can realise it?